# Swing JTable - Using key binding instead of KeyListener on Shift key

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm sorry if this has been answered before, I tried to look for the solution, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I'm new to this, so there's a chance I completely overlooked or ignored something that would have led me to an easy solution.

I've implemented a key listener for the shift key so that when the user presses shift, he enters the cell exactly one row before into the edit more (please take a look at the code below). Although, there's one problem; If the user is currently entering data into the cell, the shift key doesn't work and when debugging, we can see that the the program never even enters the key listener. I've been told to use key binding instead of key listeners to fix this problem. I've tried to follow some tutorial online and it looks like I've failed. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Two key listeners (Tab works fine, while Shift does not):

```
table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //KeyCode 9 is a key code for the Tab key
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 9) {
                if(table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn())) {
                    table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                } else {
                    table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn() + 1);
                }
            }
            //The problem occurs here
            //KeyCode 16 is a key code for the Shift key
            if (e.getKeyCode() == 16) {
                if(table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedColumn())) {
                    table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedColumn());
                    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedColumn(), table.getSelectedColumn());
                    table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedRow() + 1);
                } else {
                    table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedColumn() + 1);
                    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedColumn() + 1, table.getSelectedColumn() + 1);
                    table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedRow() + 1);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Here's my attempted (and failed) solution:

```
 class ShiftAction extends AbstractAction{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            System.out.println("Shift");
            table.editCellAt(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedColumn());
            table.setColumnSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedColumn(), table.getSelectedColumn());
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.getSelectedRow() + 1, table.getSelectedRow() + 1);
        }
    }
    shiftAction = new ShiftAction();
    table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT,KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),"doShiftAction");
    table.getActionMap().put("doShiftAction",shiftAction);
```

Hopefully the question's not too stupid, and once again, thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've been told to use key binding instead of key listeners to fix this problem.": by who?? go ask them. this will not fix your problem but increase your problems (as you rightly see now)

Comment: I've been told to do so by my Java instructor who doesn't have that much time to help me (I have a few more days left until I have to finish the project). It's not that big of a deal, I can leave it like it is, this is more of a learning experience for me.

Comment: @gpasch, yes, Key Bindings is the better solution. It is a newer and better API and addresses the focus issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.getKeyCode() == 9
```

First of all, don't use magic numbers. People reading the code don't know what "9" means. Use the provided fields from the `KeyEvent` API:  `KeyEvent.VK_???`.

> we can see that the the program never even enters the key listener.

Focus is on the JTextField being used as the editor for the cell so it receives the KeyEvent, not the table.

> I've been told to use key binding instead of key listeners to fix this problem.

You need to use the appropriate `InputMap`. In this case it should be:

```
JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: I apologize, I wish I'd thought that through. The key code for the Tab key is 9, and the key code for the Shift key is 16. I'll edit the information in immediately. I'll try to apply all of this to the code. I'm wondering, the appropriate JComponent in this case, is it JTable or JTextField?